# Changing aggregate behavior during its lifetime

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

Imagine that we have an Aggregate that has a life cycle, such that it can change its behavior during its lifetime. During the first part of its life, it can do some things and during the second part, it can do other things.

I´d like to hear opinions on how should we restrict what the aggregate can do on each phase.
To make it a little more tangible, lets take an financial trade as an aggreagate example.

- A trader creates a **trade** informing the contract, and its price.
- A risk manager validates a trade, giving a reason for such.
- The BackOffice can submit the trade to the ledger, providing  accounting information.
- After the trade is submitted, the accounting information can never be changed.

The trade clearly has 3 distinct phases, which I´ll call *Typed*, *Validated* and *Submitted*

My first thought is to pollute the aggregate with `InvalidOperationExceptions`, which I really don´t like:

```
public class Trade 
{
    private enum State { Typed, Validated, Submited }
    private State _state = State.Typed;

    public Guid Id { get; }
    public Contract Contract { get; }
    public decimal Price { get; }

    public Trade (Guid id, Contract contract, decimal price) { ... }

    private string _validationReason = null;
    private AccountingInformation _accInfo = null;

    public void Validate(string reason)  {
        if (_state != State.Typed)
            throw new InvalidOperationException (..)
        ...
        _validationReason = reason;
        _state = State.Validated;
    }

    public string GetValidationReason() {
        if (_state == State.Typed)
            throw new InvalidOperationException (..)
        return _validationReason;
    }

    public void SubmitToLedger(AccountingInformation info) {
        if ((_state != State.Validated))
            throw new InvalidOperationException (..)
        ...
    }

    public AccountingInfo GetAccountingInfo() { .. }
}
```

I can do something like a [Maybe pattern](http://wpaszek.pl/2016/12/01/maybe-class-concept-in-c/), to avoid the exceptions on the `Get...` methods. But that would not work for the behavior methods (`Validate`, `SubmitToLedger`, etc)

Oddly, if I were to be working on a functional language (such as F#), I would probably create a different type for each state.

```
type TypedTrade = { Id : Guid;  Contract: Contract; Price : decimal }

type ValidatedTrade = {  Id : Guid;  
                        Contract: Contract; 
                        Price : decimal;
                        ValidationReason : string}

type SubmittedTrade =  {  Id : Guid;  
                        Contract: Contract; 
                        Price : decimal;
                        ValidationReason : string; 
                        AccInfo : AccountingInfo }

// TypedTrade -> string -> ValidatedTrade
let validateTrade typedTrade reason = 
    ...
    { Id = typedTrade.Id; Contract = typedTrade.Contract;
            Price = typedTrade.Price; Reason = reason }

// ValidatedTrade -> AccountingInfo -> SubmittedTrade
let submitTrade validatedTrade accInfo = 
    ...
    { Id = validatedTrade.Id; 
    Contract = validatedTrade.Contract;
    Price = validatedTrade.Price; 
    Reason = validatedTrad.Reason;
    AccInfo = accInfo }
```

And the problem would gracefully go away. But to do that in OO, I would have to make my aggregate immutable and maybe create some kind o hierarchy (in which I would have to hide base methods !? ouch!).

I just wanted an opinion on what you guys do on these situations, and if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the idea of having different types for each state. Its a clean design in my opinion. From a logical view a newly created trade is definitly something different than a submitted trade.

```
public Interface ITrade
{
    Guid Id { get; }
    Contract Contract { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }
}

public class Trade : ITrade
{
    public Trade(Guid id, Contract contract, decimal price)
    {
        Id = id;
        Contract = contract;
        Price = price;
    }

    Guid Id { get; }
    Contract Contract { get; }
    decimal Price { get; }

    public ValidatedTrade Validate(string reason)
    {
        return new ValidatedTrade(this, reason);
    }
}

public class ValidatedTrade : ITrade
{
    private ITrade trade;
    private string validationReason;

    public ValidatedTrade(Trade trade, string validationReason)
    {
        this.trade = trade;
        this.validationReason = validationReason;
    }

    Guid Id { get { return trade.Id; } }
    Contract Contract { get { return trade.Contract ; } }
    decimal Price { get { return trade.Price ; } }

    public string GetValidationReason()
    {
        return validationReason;
    }

    public SubmittedTrade SubmitToLedger(AccountingInfo accountingInfo)
    {
        return new SubmittedTrade(this, accountingInfo);
    }
}

public class SubmittedTrade : ITrade
{
    private ITrade trade;
    private AccountingInfo accountingInfo;

    public SubmittedTrade(ValidatedTrade trade, AccountingInfo accountingInfo)
    {
        this.trade = trade;
        this.accountingInfo = accountingInfo;
    }

    Guid Id { get { return trade.Id; } }
    Contract Contract { get { return trade.Contract ; } }
    decimal Price { get { return trade.Price ; } }

    public AccountingInfo GetAccountingInfo() { .. }
}
```

Comment: I thought it would deviate a little from an aggregate pattern. But it does make sense. Would you use a single Repository<ITrade> ?. Probably would need some sort of Visitor Pattern too right ?

Comment: For ease of use I would suggest multuple different repository types. But thats not required. About the visitor pattern, I dont know why you would need it. For what to accomplish?

Comment: I gues I was getting ahead of myself, thinking I would eventually need a way to act upon the interface `ITrade`. In F# I would create a disciminated union to do pattern match. But you are right, it is not required up-front.

Comment: Ah I see :) Visitor pattern could be a way but it depends on what exaclty you want to achieve. Sometimes you just have an "oldschool" controller that procedurally goes through the steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could have one class per state instead of a single class. See this post by Greg Young : http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/03/09/state-pattern-misuse/

The usual problem with the State pattern is the friction with persistence concerns and especially ORMs. It's up to you to decide if the better robustness and type safety is worth the trouble.

Comment: Great post from greg young. I´ll use separate classes.